# Polymer: Style Parent Element from dom-repeat data item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, polymer-1.0

I'm pretty new to Polymer, and am developing a small Web-App to display staff members who have entered or exited the building using their electronic tags.

Currently, they are all displaying in a list, with text that says "Entered at hh:mm" or "Exited at hh:mm".

I would like to be able to grey out the avatar and reduce the elevation of the "staff-card" element.

I have a my-list element that uses iron-ajax to acquire the data and then a dom-repeat template which iterates through and displays a staff-card.

```
<iron-ajax
  auto
  url="../../api/database.json"
  handle-as="json"
  last-response="{{ajaxData}}"
  debounce-duration="300">
</iron-ajax>

<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ajaxData]]">
  <staff-card>
      <img src="{{computeAvatar()}}">
      <h2>{{item.FirstName}} {{item.Surname}}</h2>
      <p>{{setLocation(item.lastknownlocation)}} {{prettyTime(item.LastAccessTime.date)}}</p>
  </staff-card>
</template>
```

My staff-card element looks like this:

```
<paper-material elevation="2">
  <div class="card-header" layout horizontal center>
    <content select="img"></content>
    <content select="h2"></content>
    <content select="p"></content>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</paper-material>
```

So, if the item.lastknownlocation is "outside" I want to reduce the elevation of the paper-material in my staff-card and set the img to be grayscale. (I have the css for this, just not the means to apply it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Parent Element

```
<iron-ajax
  auto
  url="../../api/database.json"
  handle-as="json"
  last-response="{{ajaxData}}"
  debounce-duration="300">
</iron-ajax>

<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ajaxData]]">
  <staff-card src="{{computeAvatar()}}" header="{{item.FirstName}} {{item.Surname}}" location="{{setLocation(item.lastknownlocation)}}">
  </staff-card>
</template>
```

#### Staff Card (notice paper-material is set to ANIMATED so that elevation can be dynamically updated)

```
<dom-module id="staff-card">
  <template>
    <style>
    </style>
    <paper-material animated id="paper" elevation="{{computeElevation(location)}}">
      <img src="{{src}}">
      <h2>{{header}}</h2>
      <p>{{location}} {{time}}</p>
    </paper-material>


  </template>

  <script>
    (function() {
      'use strict';

      Polymer({
        is: 'staff-card',

        properties: {
          src: {},
          header: {},
          location: {},
          time: {},
        },
        computeElevation: function(location) {
          console.log(location);
          if (location.isOutside()) {
            return 1;
          } else {
            return 5;
          }
        },

      });
    })();
```

Comment: Chris, thank you so much for your reply.  I don't know if perhaps I didn't understand or maybe I've done something wrong but the **computeElevation** function never seems to fire; and the **last-known-location** property of the _staff-card_ gets removed when the element is rendered, although I also can't see where we used it anyway.  Any further ideas are welcomed.

Comment: Do you have this line "elevation="{{computeElevation(lastKnowLocation)}}"? That's needed for the computeElevation function to be called.

Comment: @Alex Fiorello What do you mean the last-known-location property of the staff-card gets removed when the element is rendered? Can you post your setLocation function?

Comment: Yes the function computeElevation is there and I have just discovered it isn't firing because the use here of lastKnownLocation is invalid.   If I remove that from between the brackets, the function is called, but obviously does not do what we want

I think I am getting a bit confused.  In Staff-card how is that variable lastKnownLocation being set?

Comment: Here is what I mean regarding *last-known-location* disappearing.

I put the code as you suggested:
`<staff-card last-known-location="{{setLocation(item.lastknownlocation)}} ">`

But if I run the code and view the source of the page this is what I see.

`<staff-card class="style-scope my-list">`

The same is true of the elevation attribute now, that's gone too (if computeElevation is fired)

`<paper-material id="card" class="style-scope staff-card x-scope paper-material-0">`

Comment: That's because they're properties not attributes

Comment: Oh I just noticed I wasn't returning the elevation values. Edited.

Comment: @AlexFiorello I tested it on my comp and it appears to be working. Give it a try. The only thing I didn't include was style changes for the grey out.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  With your edited post above I was able to get it to work and am over the moon.  Thanks for your time and for explaining all again clearly.

Comment: Great, happy to help!